# How to sync Garmin Connect with Google Fit?

Tags: smartwatch, google-fit, google-pixel-3a-xl

I have Garmin Swim 2.

On my Pixel 3A XL installed [Garmin Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.garmin.android.apps.connectmobile), it works fine.

But I want also see data on [Google Fit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fitness).

Unfortunately Garmin Swim 2 doesn't connect with Google Fit and I need to install third party app do this.

I installed [Health Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.appyhapps.healthsync).

Look like it's working:

[image]

But I don't see any activities in Google Fit where I didn't have my phone with me, for example swimming, sleep and so on.

On [Garmin Forum](https://forums.garmin.com/apps-software/mobile-apps-web/f/garmin-connect-web/160201/garmin-connect-sync-to-google-fit-and-samsung-health#pifragment-455=1) I found the following:

> in Settings of Google Fit, under Tracking Preferences, Turn off "
> Track your activities" Use Phone sensors to automatically track
> metrics like steps and distance.

Okay, I did this, but it didn't help.

What I should do to sync Garmin Connect with Google Fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Health Sync support, problem was solved.

Actually I have two google accounts and Goggle Fit used another account.

When I switched to correct account, everything started to work.

Answer (score 1):

if there is a problem with Health Sync, you can use the 'Report another problem' option in the Help Center, and you will get support to solve the problem.